# How to manage the Sync Adapter queue?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-contentprovider

I've made an app to be able to read API data from a website. It's read-only (for now).
I have used a Authenticator/Content Provider/Sync Adapter model and it works ok but i need to make it more performant.
My UI uses cursorloaders that ask the provider for data. Then if it doesn't find all requested data, the provider asks for a sync. It's not full syncs (too much data, too long) but targetted syncs with type of request + relevant arguments.

My pb is that, different parts of the ui may ask for similar data and i got duplicate sync requests performed even if the data they want is already getting synced from server through a previous sync request.

Is there a way to manage that in provider or sync adapter ? To prevent duplicate sync requests to be made when one is already in queue for syncing ?

I hope someone can help, thank you !

EDIT : answered in comments :)

Comment: compute hash from sync args, save last time of this hash after sync, if you do another sync check if exists saved time for the same hash if so do not sync ...

Comment: nice ! should i do that in provider or sync adapter ? And can you explain a little how i can compute a hash ?

Comment: I would rather choose `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.onPerformSync` ... about hashes: depends on your needs the point of hashes is that for same args you should get same value but also you should avoid the colission... it really depends on arg(parameters)

Comment: ok, understood :) Thanks a lot for your quick answer !